# From deprecated cliOnline to OnlineNodeCommand

Tags: jenkins, groovy

So I created this groovy script but read that the `cliOnline()` command is deprecated.
But I can't seem to figure out how to actually change my code to use `hudson.model.Hudson.instance.OnlineNodeCommand()`?

[deprecated cliOnline](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Computer.html#cliOnline())

```
def nodes_checklist = ["PD100069", "PD100070", "PD100090", "PD10756"]; // List of nodes which should be turned online
def jenkinsNodes = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getNodes() // Get all existing nodes on this Jenkins URL
for(def node_checker: nodes_checklist) {
    for(def node: jenkinsNodes) {
        if(node.getNodeName().contains(node_checker)) {
            println "The node " + node.getNodeName() + "'s offline status: " + node.toComputer().isOffline()
            if (node.toComputer().isOffline()){
                println "Turning " + node.getNodeName() + " online"
                node.toComputer().cliOnline() // If node is offline, turn it online
                println node.getNodeName() + "'s online status: " node.toComputer().isOnline()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to rewrite this to use the non-deprecated version?

Comment: i think you are not supposed to use that in your own scripts (thats why i suppose it has been depreated), it is internal to the cli implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/a351a55418e69a01bf6ffa47fa8130171f6012da/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Computer.java#L560) depricated method, it simply calls a non depricated [method](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/a351a55418e69a01bf6ffa47fa8130171f6012da/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/Computer.java#L705) `setTemporarilyOffline(boolean temporarilyOffline, OfflineCause cause)`. So not sure why this was depricated. Anyway instead of using `cliOnline()` you can use `setTemporarilyOffline`. Check the following.

```
node.getComputer().setTemporarilyOffline(false, null)
```

Some proper code with a proper cause. Cause is not really needed when setting the node online though.

```
import hudson.slaves.OfflineCause.UserCause

def jenkinsNodes = Jenkins.instance.getNodes()
  for(def node: jenkinsNodes) {
      if (node.getComputer().isTemporarilyOffline()){  
           node.getComputer().setTemporarilyOffline(false, null)
      }
  }
```

Setting to temporarily offline

```
UserCause cause =  new UserCause(User.current(), "This is a automated process!!")
node.getComputer().setTemporarilyOffline(true, cause)
```